# Restore man user

Tags: users, user-management

For some dislexic reason (or haven't slept enough) I typed

```
deluser man
```

instead of the more common

```
man deluser
```

... as you can imagine, I just deleted man user! Never happened before...

How can I properly restore system's man user?

Comment: This is a perfect example why you don't use root for things that don't require root.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is a utility called `update-passwd` that appears to do this safely for you:

```
NAME
       update-passwd - safely update /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow and /etc/group

SYNOPSIS
       update-passwd [options]

DESCRIPTION
       update-passwd   handles   updates   of   /etc/passwd,  /etc/shadow  and
       /etc/group on running Debian systems.  It compares the current files to
       master  copies, distributed in the base-passwd package, and updates all
       entries in the global system range (that is, 0–99).
```

First check the current entry

```
$ getent passwd man
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
```

Now let's delete it

```
$ sudo deluser man
[sudo] password for steeldriver: 
Removing user `man' ...
Warning: group `man' has no more members.
Done.
```

Check it's really gone

```
$ getent passwd man
$
```

Then

```
$ sudo update-passwd --dry-run
Adding group "man" (12)
Adding user "man" (6)
Would commit 2 changes
```

OK let's do it

```
$ sudo update-passwd
2 changes have been made, rewriting files
```

Now confirm the restored password file entry

```
$ getent passwd man
man:*:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
```

Comment: Excellent + upvoted.  Please accept this instead of mine ;)